# logistic law-differential equations.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The population of New York City would satisfy the logistic law $$\frac{dp}{dt}=\frac{1}{25}p-\frac{1}{25 \times 10^6}p^2 $$ where $t$ is measured in years, if we neglected the high emigration and homicide rates

(a) Modify this equation to take into account the fact that 9,000 people per year move from the city, and 1,000 people per year are murdered.

(b) Assume that the population of New York City was 8,000,000 in 1970. Find the population for all future time. What happens as t->$\infty$?

so for (a)
I'm having a hard time on how to modify it, so if anyone can guide me, that would be great.

As for (b)

Would I use p(t)=$\frac{ap_0}{bp_0+(a-bp_0)e^{-a(t-t_0)}}$ where a=$\frac{1}{25}$ and b=$\frac{1}{25 \times 10^6}$ and I'm guessing the $p_0$ comes from (a). Also for the time portion (t-$t_0$), would I do (2015-1970)?